# Restore to a Point-In-Time between two Mongodump backups

Tags: mongodb, mongodump, mongorestore

Let's say I have mongodump backups taken daily at 00:00.
How do I restore to a point-in-time at 12:00, but for a day earlier than the current oplog contains? Assume the oplog always contains more than 24 hours worth of changes.

I can obviously restore to Day 1 00:00 or Day 2 00:00, and I could dump the existing oplog if that date was still present.

Comment: By your comments it seems you already know what needs to be done and you're just looking for an easier way to do it, as far as I know there is no easier way.
you can follow this blog post, it gives a pretty good description of all the steps you need to do: https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/01/25/mongodb-point-in-time-restore/

Comment: Not really. When I restored Day 2 (full database), the oplog only contained entries from the point where I started the restore, not for the full 24 hours. I'm restoring to a PIT before the original oplog.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you took your snapshot, restored over your production server, and then tried to dump+restore the oplog?

If you want to restore over your production server you need to dump the oplog itself prior to restoring the backup. Otherwise your oplog will be wiped by the restore. In https://alexmarquardt.com/2017/01/25/mongodb-point-in-time-restore/ they restore to a spare server.

If your point-in-time is before the horizon of the original oplog, i.e. your restore point has fallen off the oplog, then unless you were using one of the backup products, no point in time restore is possible.